# Who started the trend of removing ing from gerunds and what is the motivation?

Tags: grammar, writing-style, gerunds

I've noticed a trend developing over the past few years where gerunds are being emasculated (cutting off their "ing-alings" by golly!!!)

- On my credit card's website: "spend analysis"
- All over the web: "compute resources"
- In American football: "run game"
- In the *Colorado Driver Handbook*: "drive test"

Who started this trend, and why?

Comment: Oh, it don't mean a thing if it ain't got that ing! doo wah doo wah doo wah doo wah

Comment: Damn, I just realised my state calls it the "drive test" too. And I'm not in the US. The state above me still calls it "driving test." This is weird.

Comment: It's been happening to English suffixes for the last 500 years or so. Zero-affix morphology is the normal English way; think un-suffixed noun compounds like _Sierra Rim Canyon County School Board Room_. Compare to Spanish or French, which would have lots of _de_'s and _la_'s. Many compounds that previously required _-ing_ forms no longer do; that's all. This kind of stuff happens all the time.

Comment: Certainly in web pages and even more so on the dreaded PowerPoint slide, contraction like this is done to save space and/or to permit characters of larger size and therefore easier readability. But I doubt that was the trigger for the general trend.

Comment: @zebrafish Drive test but drivers ed? Why not drive ed?

Comment: You aren't going to be able to trace this to one person and understand their motivation. You might get better answers just asking for the history of it?

Comment: Disappear-ing Act. [Paranormal Ship Walk Tour](https://www.queenmary.com/tours/attractions-night/paranormal-ship-walk/),  [Lingerie Wash Powder](https://www.hankypanky.com/lingerie-wash-powder.html), [cook top](https://www.frigidaire.com/Kitchen-Appliances/Cooktops/?gclid=Cj0KCQjw2f7bBRDVARIsAAwYBBsBelh15QSsuA41ZQi-xRXBIEOnzI3-M_lSExra19v3zNYOr7kL5qEaAv8EEALw_wcB&dclid=CP-A_beIht0CFQx8wQod_0YN4A), [Mix Console](https://www.soundonsound.com/techniques/all-mixed)

Answer (score 2):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> It's been happening to English suffixes for the last 500 years or so. Zero-affix morphology is the normal English way; think un-suffixed noun compounds like *Sierra Rim Canyon County School Board Room*. Compare to Spanish or French, which would have lots of *de*'s and *la*'s. Many compounds that previously required *-ing* forms no longer do; that's all. This kind of stuff happens all the time.